# I want to write spread sheet with service account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets-api

I use Ruby.

I want to access a Google Spread Sheet.
However, in the document, the access method is not listed depending on the service account.
I referred to the following articles.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ruby

Please tell me how to access by service account.

Or please introduce a helpful article.

Comment: create a google sheet and share it with your sevice accounts as an editor.

Answer (score 0):

I can access google spread sheet with service account from ruby programming.
I found document.
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/docs/usage-guide.md#getting-automatic-credentials